# How to run my Android application on my Android device?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, galaxy

I've created an Android application with Eclipse, and I ran it on the `Android Virtual Machine`, and it worked great. But I want to run on my physical device.

I have `Samsung Galaxy Poket`. How to run the application on the Galaxy?

**More details that might help:**

- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate.
- Full Android device model: Samsung Galaxy Pocket gt-s5300.
- Android version: 2.3.6.
- Eclipse distribution: 3.7 Indigo.

Comment: You can reference my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12912603/1050058)

Answer (score 1):

So firstly you need to switch your phone in to USB Debug mode, this can be done in the android settings menu depending on your version of android it can be in one of a few places but generally it will be under the development section of the settings. You'll also need to check the check box that allows you to install apps from unknown sources (usually found in the security section of the settings). Once that is done, Run your app like you usually would from eclipse and your device should pop up in the same list that all your running emulators do. If you still don't see your device, Install Kies from the Samsung website, This will install all of the USB drivers needed for your phone to be recognized in the ADT Plugin.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Read the official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/tools/device.html