# how to test my application in my android device

Tags: android

I have build my first application for Android Phone in Eclipse.

I want to test my app in my real device. I have not made apk till now.

Can anyone please provide me the step by step guideline on how to load my app from eclipse to my device and run it.

Comment: Install the USB drivers for your device, connect the device to your computer, right-click your project in Eclipse, select `Run As`, select `Android Application`.

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910697/how-to-connect-the-device-to-the-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

> You need to enable USB debugging on the phone itself (by starting the Settings application and selecting *Applications* > *Development* > *USB Debugging*), install the Android USB device driver if you haven’t already (Windows only), and then plug the phone into your computer using the USB cable that came with the phone.
>
> Close the emulator window if it’s already open. As long as the phone is plugged in, Eclipse will load and run applications on the phone instead. You need to right-click the project and select *Run As* > *Android Application*.

or

> In eclipse you go to run->build or if you have build automatically turned on you can go into the projects file structure and just copy the .apk file out of the bin folder. You can put this on the devices SD card and install it from there. No need to do the export unsigned apk thing.

Comment: I am applying the first method as said by you but the application is running on the emulator only

Comment: better you try the second way, some times you dot have USB drivers for your device.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

An must for device debugging is Mobile usb drivers and You should go to SDK manager->extras->usb pluggin download that pacakge....

Answer (score 0):

This may help http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html.

If you're on Windows you will need to install the USB driver. Then, on your Devices tab (Window->Show View->Other->Android->Devices) you should see a new row appear when you connect your device to your workstation with a USB cable (although LG handsets are problematic in my experience)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows you will need to install the USB driver. Then, on your Devices tab (Window->Show View->Other->Android->Devices) you should see a new row appear when you connect your device to your workstation with a USB cable (although LG handsets are problematic in my experience).