# Getting My Galaxy S3 to work with ADB on Windows 7?

Tags: android, adb

I have installed Java ADT Eclipse on my Windows 7 Machine.

I have installed KIES3.

I have installed the drivers from http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows onto my PC, which gives me a folder full of this stuff:

```
29/04/2014  21:07    <DIR>          .
29/04/2014  21:07    <DIR>          ..
29/04/2014  21:06    <DIR>          01_Simmental
29/04/2014  21:06    <DIR>          02_Siberian
29/04/2014  21:06    <DIR>          03_Swallowtail
29/04/2014  21:06    <DIR>          04_semseyite
27/04/2014  22:58    <DIR>          05_Sloan
27/04/2014  22:58    <DIR>          06_Spencer
29/04/2014  21:06    <DIR>          07_Schorl
27/04/2014  22:58    <DIR>          08_EMPChipset
29/04/2014  21:06    <DIR>          09_Hsp
29/04/2014  21:06    <DIR>          11_HSP_Plus_Default
27/04/2014  22:58    <DIR>          12_Symbian_USB_Download_Driver
27/04/2014  22:58    <DIR>          15_Symbian_Samsung_PC_DLC_Driver
29/04/2014  21:07    <DIR>          16_Shrewsbury
27/04/2014  22:58    <DIR>          17_EMP_Chipset2
27/04/2014  22:58    <DIR>          18_Zinia_Serial_Driver
27/04/2014  22:58    <DIR>          19_VIA_driver
29/04/2014  21:07    <DIR>          20_NXP_Driver
27/04/2014  22:58    <DIR>          21_Searsburg
27/04/2014  22:58    <DIR>          22_WiBro_WiMAX
29/04/2014  21:07    <DIR>          24_flashusbdriver
29/04/2014  21:07    <DIR>          25_escape
26/12/2013  06:43         1,057,536 dgderapi.dll
26/12/2013  06:41           525,792 DIFxAPI.dll
29/04/2014  21:07    <DIR>          lang
26/12/2013  06:44         1,523,968 Uninstall.exe#
```

However, I still can't work out how to get my Samsung Galaxy to be recognished as an ADB device.

I have tried every answer that I can find on this site, but none of them are working.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the USB cable that came with your s3?

Comment: Did you enable USB debugging on your S3?

Comment: Yes, developer mode is on.  Yes, I am using the original USB cable.

Comment: I just want to clarify that enabling developer mode is not the same as enabling USB debugging. You still have to turn on debugging after you enable developer mode.

Comment: Thanks Chue!  That worked!  If you write your comment as an answer I will give you the bounty.

Comment: @Chuex Post the comment as your answer please..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374739/getting-my-galaxy-s3-to-work-with-adb-on-windows-7?noredirect=1#comment35981060_23374739) it appears as though you have the developer options enabled, but have not yet enabled USB debugging.

In order for ADB to see your device, you must do both. 
The following is from [Setting up a Device for Development](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up), and talks about how to enable USB debugging:

> - On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under Settings > Applications > Development.
> - On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer options.
>
>   Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

1. Download Kies 3 from http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/
2. Run it
3. Go to Tools > Reinstall Device drivers
4. Phone should prompted to allow USB debugging

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910697/how-to-connect-the-device-to-the-eclipse).. it says

Check if your computer had your phone driver. I assume that you use Windows. `Open Device Manager`

At a command prompt, in the Start Search box, or in the Run box, type the following command: `mmc devmgmt.msc`

. Otherwise : check [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754221%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

If you find your phone name or ADB Interface so you got driver. Try to restart `DDMS` or restart your `Eclipse`.

If you don't find your device or see something Other device with yellow question mark so try to install driver by browsing on your phone to Settings - Developer Options - Enable developer option - Enable USB debugging - Plug your phone to computer. Windows will ask you to install driver.

3, Update Google USB driver in Android SDK Manager (in Eclipse) or search Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i driver

4.Some weird case i got on some devices.

**Nexus S**: disable Developer option. Restart phone. Enable again. Windows ask to install driver or you will see it in Eclipse.

**HTC** phone or **Samsung** : change Connectivity Option on phone to Charge only (Swipe status bar. Check notifications displayed). Some phone set it to some kind of Sync data so Windows can not recognize device.

Another answer in the same link tells you the steps to select the avd manually..It is as below..

**Step 1**

Go to Run Configuration

**Step2**

Select the Target

**Step 3**

Choose Always prompt to pick device.Click Ok

**Step 4**

Now run your project you should see the emulator and your device. Select your device and click ok.

Check these steps.. Hope that it helps..

Answer (score 0):

My Galaxy S3 uses `SAMSUNG USB Composite Device Driver`.

The file is `ssudbus.sys` in the `25_escape` folder.

So go into the Device Manager click on the unrecognized S3 device and install the driver from the `25_escape` folder.

---

Also make sure you enabled the USB Debugging in your Phone (Developer Options).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if your USB debugging is on or not. Same happened with me and even after re installing the drivers, i was not able to make my device recognizable. 
Then someone told me that developer and USB debugging modes are actually different.

You need to go to setting->developers option. on the developers option and check the USB debugging check box. It will give you an error which you can ignore and then try.

Hope this helps, it did for me. :)