# Cannot connect Samsung GT-S5830V Android to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am having trouble connecting a Samsung GT-S5830V Android to Eclipse. I have followed the instructions provided in the Using Hardware Devices Android Guide as well as installing the latest drivers and Kies for my phone. I have also followed the instructions in [How to connect the device to Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910697/how-to-connect-the-device-to-eclipse) with no luck.

The results of my work so far are:

- Three devices shown under Other Devices in Device Manager.

  - BCM21553-Thunderbird
  - CDC Abstract Control Model (ACM)
  - CDC ACM Data

Kies shows it's trying to constantly connect to the phone with no progress.

ADB shows a blank screen when I run adb devices.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might solve or get this issue sorted out?

Comment: Sounds like the device isn't set up properly.  Are you certain the ADB drivers for the Samsung GT are installed? You could try re-installing them or look at the universal ADB driver.  https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by following the instructions provided in [Google Android USB Driver and ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709263/google-android-usb-driver-and-adb/15609366#15609366) using the following lines in the android_winusb.inf file:

```
;Samsung GT-S5830V
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_685E
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_685E&REV_0400&MI_03
```