# Android Device is not visible inside the eclipse for debugging

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new in android, using eclipse and want to launch the application in my `MICROMAX A94` mobile. its suggest me to launch through the Emulator , not on the real device what can i do

Comment: yes i have downloaded the driver of my phone

Comment: did you set it to allow usb debbuging?

Comment: have you enabled the Developer Option in your real device?

Comment: Enabling developer options on your phone and enable usb debugging

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910697/how-to-connect-the-device-to-eclipse

Comment: Yes i have enabled the developer option in device

Answer (score 0):

Install software named moborobo in your system to detect your device in eclips DDMS.

You can download it from : [MoboRobo Software](http://moborobo.en.softonic.com/download)

Comment: well i can see , but howcome its helpful to lauch the apk on real device .. its seems to be something like personalised application.

Comment: you can go through this to know about this application and how its works : http://moborobo.en.softonic.com/