# Android Studio: Android Device Monitor not showing my device

Tags: android, android-studio, sony, sony-xperia

My real device is **Sony Xperia c6502** with android version 4.3
I'm sure I connect it to my computer and I turn **Developer options/ USB debugging** on

In SDK manager, Google USB driver is already installed.

[image: I have already turned the option on]

[image: It is connected to my computer by USB cable]

I downloaded Xperia Z Driver from this page:http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/
But I don't know how to use it
[image]

No PTP mode option in USB Connectivity in my phone
[image]

My device is not shown in Android Device Monitor and thus I can't run app test on my phone.

How to let my Android Studio catch my phone?

[image]

Comment: Try pluggin & unplugging it several times until you get message on your phone `Trust this computer?`

Comment: @agamov not working, sir

Comment: @JeanYang Try to manually start `adb` server before plugging your phone to the computer. Check if it is able to detect your phone.

Comment: @boxed__l How to do it? Nothing executable found in the zip

Comment: @JeanYang Check [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) link for instructions/commands.

Comment: You can check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910697/how-to-connect-the-device-to-eclipse/12912603#12912603) for similar solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device here is the answer for your question.

Answer (score 11):

Some possible solutions:

- On your notification bar, expand it and click the connection. Then select connect as `Camera (PTP)` (not as media device)
- Try with another USB cable.
- <strike>Go to your SDK manager and install `Google USB Driver`</strike> (I see you updated your answer regarding this)
- Follow the instructions on [OEM USD Drivers](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)

Comment: On my notification bar, I expand it and click the connection, but nothing popup or happened
My Google USB driver is already installed.
Not working

Comment: Check your connection is PTP and not MTP (http://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/)

Comment: There are only two options: Media transfer mode(MTP) and Mass storage mode(MSC).  What should I do? I select MSC and it is still not working

Comment: On [this xda-developers question](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2240786) someone was having a similar problem with the same model and they link a solution that might help you.

Comment: It is not working. I installed Emma but even Emma can't connect to my phone

Answer (score 4):

I tried all the possible solutions given above but cannot detect my device. Finally, I come to know device drivers are not installed.

You can install it like: Go to **Tools > Android > SDK Manager> SDK Tools > Google USB drivers**.

Make sure it's installed.

Comment: I got same issue and i resolved with your solution. I saved my lots of time. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Google to [download usb driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html)
2. Plug in your Android phone

Open device manager

Right click on your phone with exclaimation mark

Select update driver software

[image]

3. Browse my computer for driver sofware

[image]

4. Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer

[image]

5. Select Android Device

[image]

6. Click Have Disk

[image]

7. Select the inf file

[image]

8. Select Android Composite ADB Interface and click next and Yes to install

[image]

9. And your are done

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do a CTRL+ALT+DEL and bring up the task manager.  Look for ADB.EXE and end task it.

Sometimes it will hang and prevent device enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work if `USB tethering` is on.

Comment: Where can this be found?