# Android Device Monitor did not display the process I want ,but display others,why?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-device-monitor

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/407cY.png)

here is the image. I can't find my app's process, but others I can see. why did this happen? what should do? Thanks.

Comment: Add  android:debuggable="true" in the manifest file. <application
        android:debuggable="true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you get errors like below:

- Unable to get view server version from device;
- Unable to get view server protocol version from device
- Unable to get the focused window from device
- Unable to debug device

try to check these points below:

- if signed app running on the phone, DDMS can't get the process info;
  otherwise, can.
- if use Virtual Device, then the DDMS&HierarchyView is useful;

Answer (score 0):

Some possible solutions:

On your notification bar, expand it and click the connection. Then select connect as Camera (PTP) (not as media device)
Try with another USB cable.
Go to your SDK manager and install Google USB Driver (I see you updated your answer regarding this)
Follow the instructions on OEM USD Drivers

Comment: thanks.this is similar to @Logain's answer in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717298/android-studio-android-device-monitor-not-showing-my-device), I had read that and try, no useful. I can find my device, but cannot see my process.

Answer (score 0):

reinstall app from IDE (if app process running stop it from IDE or force stop if through android setting)

if nothing happened try restart ADB

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
```