# Connect Phone To Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

How can I connect my phone to Android Eclipse, That The Projects Executed In My Phone Instead Of Android Virtual Device
thanks.

Comment: Check [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910697/how-to-connect-the-device-to-eclipse)

Comment: Maybe try Android Studio instead of Eclipse, and then take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html). Eclipse is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

1- Enable USB debugging On your Android device, select Settings > Developer options.

2- Connect the Android device to your development machine using a USB cable.

more: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

**Note:** On Android 4.2 and later, the developer options are hidden by default. To enable the developer options, select Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have to go settings then turn on debugging option in your mobile then press run option in eclips then select your device then you will see your app will run in your mobile for more assistant go to here http://www.developer.com/ws/android/connecting-your-android-device-to-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to consider is whether you have installed the OEM USB drivers for any devices you wish to use, as specified [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html). Then you must enable USB debugging on your phone (details will differ slightly depending on phone manufacturer and Android version).

The bigger elephant in the tent is that support for Android development in Eclipse [ended in December](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html) so you will want to move to Android Studio as soon as possible.